# Image resize with Crop

Tags: jquery, resize, crop

I want to create a function that after an image upload, will allow a user to resize an image. But the image must be behind a crop frame and the user must be able to drag/move/resize the image behind the crop frame.
[image]
Here is a screenshot of what I am thinking of.

Please can anyone point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Something like [JCrop](http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/)?

Comment: Hi, I have looked at most of the popular jquery plugins and none seemed to meet my requirement. Have you managed to do something similar with jCrop? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain, how `x` and `y` plugins are missing the mark? (Probably best in the question.) It's tuff to write a plugin from scratch :).

Comment: Hi, Josh, the big factor is, I need to combine resizing with cropping. What I need is not true cropping, as in the image above, the crop frame is static and will not move. So basically you "crop" the image by resizing it and dragging it around until you are happy with how it looks in the "crop frame" Please shoot if you have any more questions, Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd give [JRAC](https://github.com/trepmag/jrac) a look. Their [demo page](http://www.trepmag.ch/z/jrac/example/) seems to cover your use case almost exactly.

Comment: Hey Josh, that looks close enough, thanks for all your help. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

It's probably to late for response but try this if you want to do that automaticaly:  http://code.google.com/p/resize-crop/

Comment: This is link only answer. Please add more information in it

Comment: Never hurts to have answers for other people finding the question

Answer (score 5):

a little too late to find this question I had to write a plugin myself to solve the same problem, please take a look here https://github.com/joseluistorres/dragcrop and let me know if you have any questions/comments/feedback.